# Trying to do a math quiz in python

Tags: python

I am trying to make a math quiz on python, and I am trying not to use random. When I set user input to the answer of the problem and then try to run it, it says its wrong. Why? Here is apart of my code. When I answer '78' correctly, it says sorry that is not right.

```
def problem1():
    raw_input('36 + 42 = ')
    if input == '78':
        print('Correct!')
    else:
        print('Sorry that is not right.')
```

Comment: capture the return value of `raw_input` and use it in the next line where you're currently using `input`.

Comment: So I see -- thanks for the catch, and my apologies.

Comment: @Carcigenicate  No problem: I goofed; you corrected me; problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `raw_input`, but not saving its returned string, which is the user's input. Then you're comparing the existing `input` function against `"78"` which will never be correct.

Just save the users input properly then use it in the comparison:

```
inp = raw_input('36 + 42 = ')
if inp == '78':
```